# python module to decode OSX plist integer dates?

Tags: python, macos, timestamp, plist, datestamp

Is there a python module/snippet which can decode the integer datestamps contained in OSX - specifically mail - plists?

EG, this bit:

```
<key>date-sent</key>    
<integer>1264001747</integer>
```

is likely in Jan 2010.

How to deconstruct? I'm aware of the very good plistlib - but this only gets me to that integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1264001747)
datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 20, 10, 35, 47)
```

The value `1264001747` is the timestamp given in seconds from epoch. The returned `datetime` object is shown in the order `(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)`

Comment: Of course - and thanks for that. I was thrown off by other examples - perhaps even on SO? - which were dividing. Duh.Using the function straight up works perfectly. Thanks!